Calculated Column IF statement limit?
I am trying to assign numerical values based on a list of countries on a SharePoint List (SharePoint in Microsoft 365). I want to autofill a column with numbers based on another column. I have no problem doing this up to 20 if statements. Past that, I get an error.
This is what I have:
=IF(Country="Australia",7,IF(Country="Austria",8,IF(Country="Belgium",13,IF(Country="Canada",26,IF(Country="Czechia",41,IF(Country="Denmark",43,IF(Country="Estonia",51,IF(Country="European Commission",54,IF(Country="Finland",55,IF(Country="France",56,IF(Country="Germany",60,IF(Country="Greece",63,IF(Country="Hungary",68,IF(Country="Ireland",74,IF(Country="Other",999,IF(Country="United States",163,IF(Country="United Kingdom",162,IF(Country="Türkiye",157,IF(Country="The Netherlands",153,IF(Country="Switzerland",148))))))))))))))))))))

However if I add another IF statement i.e. IF(Country="Sweden",147 and add the tail ), I get an error.
Any advice?

wouldn't it be easier to use a Lookup column?

I’m checking how the things are going on about this issue. Whether the answer helps you?

This is a known limitation with SharePoint calculated column formulas.
You can use maximum 19 nested IF functions in calculated column formula.
If you have more than 19 nested IF functions/conditions, you can concatenate those using & in the formula.
Example:
IF(State="AL","Alabama",
IF(State="AK","Alaska",
IF(State="AZ","Arizona",
IF(State="AR","Arkansas",
IF(State="CA","California",
IF(State="CO","Colorado",
IF(State="CT","Connecticut",
IF(State="DE","Delaware",
IF(State="FL","Florida",
IF(State="GA","Georgia",
IF(State="HI","Hawaii",
IF(State="ID","Idaho",
IF(State="IL","Illinois",
IF(State="IN","Indiana",
IF(State="IA","Iowa",
IF(State="KS","Kansas",
IF(State="KY","Kentucky",
IF(State="LA","Louisiana",
IF(State="ME","Maine",""))))))))))))))))))) &
IF(State="MD","Maryland",
IF(State="MA","Massachusetts",
IF(State="MI","Michigan",
IF(State="MN","Minnesota",
IF(State="MS","Mississippi",
IF(State="MO","Missouri",
IF(State="MT","Montana",
IF(State="NE","Nebraska",
IF(State="NV","Nevada",
IF(State="NH","New Hampshire",
IF(State="NJ","New Jersey",
IF(State="NM","New Mexico",
IF(State="NY","New York",
IF(State="NC","North Carolina",
IF(State="ND","North Dakota",
IF(State="OH","Ohio",
IF(State="OK","Oklahoma",
IF(State="OR","Oregon",
IF(State="PA","Pennsylvania",""))))))))))))))))))) &
IF(State="RI","Rhode Island",
IF(State="SC","South Carolina",
IF(State="SD","South Dakota",
IF(State="TN","Tennessee",
IF(State="TX","Texas",
IF(State="UT","Utah",
IF(State="VT","Vermont",
IF(State="VA","Virginia",
IF(State="WA","Washington",
IF(State="WV","West Virginia",
IF(State="WI","Wisconsin","")))))))))))

References:

What is the workaround for limit in nested if statements in sharepoint calculated column? (above example is from this reference)
SharePoint List - Multiple IF AND function in calculated column

Note:

Sometimes comma(,) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(;) instead of comma(,).
Use correct display name of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
Wrap column names inside [] if your column name has space in it. For example: [My Column Name].

